# How to get attributes and features after loading data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

If the output of X=load_data() is:

```
(array([[ 47., 100.,  27., ...,  90.,  40.,  98.],
       [  0.,  89.,  27., ...,   2., 100.,   6.],
       [  0.,  57.,  31., ...,  25.,  16.,   0.],
       ...,
       [ 56., 100.,  27., ...,  93.,  38.,  93.],
       [ 19., 100.,   0., ...,  97.,  10.,  81.],
       [ 38., 100.,  37., ...,  26.,  65.,   0.]], dtype=float32), array([8, 2, 1, ..., 0, 0, 4]))
(array([[ 47., 100.,  27., ...,  90.,  40.,  98.],
       [  0.,  89.,  27., ...,   2., 100.,   6.],
       [  0.,  57.,  31., ...,  25.,  16.,   0.],
       ...,
       [ 56., 100.,  27., ...,  93.,  38.,  93.],
       [ 19., 100.,   0., ...,  97.,  10.,  81.],
       [ 38., 100.,  37., ...,  26.,  65.,   0.]], dtype=float32), array([8, 2, 1, ..., 0, 0, 4]))
```

And the my attributes are the array of `2000*16` and targets `16*1`.From this data, how can I extract `attributes` and `targets`? I don't know when I have a tuple, how to extract the info I need by correct indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
for row in dataset:
    for inputs,predicted in zip(row[0],row[1]):
        print("Inputs %s = %s"%(inputs,predicted))
```